# Parsing "\t" as field value in tab seperated file python

Tags: python, parsing, csv

I have tab separated text file and I was parsing it by using csv file reader and using `\t` as a delimiter. My question is what if any field contains `\t` as   field value?

Example txt file :

```
id   acct_id  name
1      1      weary
2      2       \t
3      4       \tisaw
```

Example code:

```
import csv
with open('txtfile.txt', 'rb') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t', quoting="")
for row in reader:
    print row
```

Is there any possible way to parse this file?

Comment: That file does not use `/t` as a delimiter, it uses tabs, so it is no trouble reading a value of `/t`.

Comment: Did you mean /t or \t?  \t is a tab character, /t is two different characters

Comment: sorry i will edit it by the way its "\t" as a delimiter and as a field value

Comment: The two characters backslash and `t` are different from the single tab character denoted as `\t` in a Python string.

Comment: If CSV fields contain special characters (field or line separator characters, then the only way to parse them in the general case is if the characters are escaped (e.g. with a preceeding '\') or if the fields themselves are quoted. In you case, if you know that only the final field can contain tabs, then you can parse the file quite easily manually (but not using the csv module).